# Stroustrup's C++ Book exercise

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ from Stroustrup's book: *Programming: Principles and Practice using C++*. I'm on *Chapter 6* and we're writing a calculator and now:

> I have to add a factorial clause which bids stronger than `*` and `/`. In the original program we had 3 levels, `primary` (floating point literals & parentheses), `terms` (* and /) and `expressions` (+ or -).
>   What `expression` does is call `term`, to collect its left hand side and so on. In order to implement the factorial I've added a `fact()` between `term`and `primary()`, in order to bid it tighter.
>   Before adding `fact()` the calculator was working perfectly fine. Then I added `fact` in order to take data from `primary` and `term` is now taking data from `fact`.

Now on to the questions:

Q1: As I already said, before adding `fact` everything was fine. Now the only correct equation which is output is the `term`. When I try to do other arithmetics it only prints me the last inputted number. Where did I messed the other operations.

Q2: (kind of off topic) Why when I try to exit the program (which is by entering `'q'` it takes me three or four times entering `'q'` until it exits.

Here is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"


class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value
    Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Token_stream {
public:
    Token_stream();         // make a Token_stream that reads from cin
    Token get();            // get a Token
    void putback(Token t);  // put a Token back
private:
    bool full;      // is there a Token in the buffer
    Token buffer;   // here is where we keep a Token put back using putback();
};

// Constructor
Token_stream::Token_stream()
    :full(false),buffer(0)
{
}

Token_stream ts;

void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
    if (full)  error("putback() into a full buffer"); // checks if we're using putback() twice
    buffer = t;  // copy t to buffer
    full = true; // buffer is now full
}

Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) {     // do we already have a Token ready?
                // remove Token from buffer
        full = false;
        return buffer;
    }

    char ch;
    cin >> ch; // note that >> skips whitespace

    switch(ch) {
    case ';':   // for "print"
    case 'q':   // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '{': case '}': case '!': case'+': case '-': case'/': case '*':
        return Token(ch);  // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);        // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;
        return Token('8',val);  // let '8' represent a "number"
        break;
    }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
        return 0;
    }
}



Token get_token()    // read a token from cin
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {

    case 'q':
    case ';':
    case '(': case ')': case '{': case '}': case '!': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {
            cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
            double val;
            cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
            return Token('8',val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
        }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
        return 0;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double expression();  // read and evaluate a Expression

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double term();        // read and evaluate a Term

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double primary()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '(':    // handle '(' expression ')'
        {
            double d = expression();
            t = ts.get();
            if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected");
            return d;
        }
    case '{':    // handle '(' expression ')'
            {
                double d = expression();
                t = ts.get();
                if (t.kind != '}') error("'}' expected");
                return d;
            }
    case '8':            // we use '8' to represent a number
        return t.value;  // return the number's value
    default:
        return 0;
        error("primary expected");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
try {
        double val = 0;
        while(cin)
        {
            Token t = ts.get();

            if(t.kind == 'q') break; //'q' for quit
            if(t.kind == ';')
                cout << "=" << val << "\n";
            else
                ts.putback(t);
            val = expression();
        }

    keep_window_open("q");
}
catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    keep_window_open ("q");
    return 1;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "exception \n";
    keep_window_open ("q");
    return 2;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double expression()
{
    double left = term();      // read and evaluate a Term
    Token t = ts.get();        // get the next token

    while(true) {
        switch(t.kind) {
        case '+':
            left += term();    // evaluate Term and add
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '-':
            left -= term();    // evaluate Term and subtract
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        default:
            ts.putback(t);
            return left;       // finally: no more + or -: return the answer
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double factorial(double val)
{
    double res=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=val; i++)
        res *= i;
    return res;
}

double fact()
{
    double left = primary();
    Token t = ts.get();

    switch(t.kind)
    {
    case '!':
        {   double res = factorial(left);
            return res;
        }
    default:
        return left;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

double term()
{
    double left = fact();
    Token t = ts.get();     // get the next token

    while(true) {
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':
            left *= fact();
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '/':
            {
                double d = fact();
                if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
                left /= d;
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            }
        default:
            ts.putback(t);
            return left;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I'm being unspecific enough.
That's my first time I'm posting such a thread.

Comment: When you used the debugger, and single stepped through the code, which statement is giving the issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Starting from your second question:**

You need to press `q` several times as you have it as an argument in:

```
keep_window_open("q");
```

so, every time you exit your `while` loop, it waits for you to enter `q` in order to close the console.

**Regarding your factorial function:**

Specify your calculator *Grammar* : write the order of precedence of the existing operations, i.e. the call order the functions that contain them. This will make it easier for you to incorporate new functionality.

It will be good idea to put `factorial` as additional `case` into `primary()`, as *parentheses* have higher order of precedence (called earlier) than *multiplication, division, etc* in `term()`.

Here is one possible implementation:

```
double primary(){
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '{':{
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != '}') error("'}' expected");
        return d;
    }
    case '(':    // handles '(' expression ')'{    
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected");
        return d;
    }
    case '8': case '!':{
        // include a test whether the number is integer and > 0 
        if(is_factorial()){
            double d  = factorial(t.value);
            t = ts.get();
            return d;
        }
        else return t.value;
    }
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}
```

where:

```
/*
   Non-member method: factorial.
   Use: double fact = factorial(double);
   This funnction provides factorial operator.
*/
double factorial(double num){
   if(num <= 1) return 1;
   return num*factorial(num-1);
}
```

and

```
/*
   Non-member method: is_factorial.
   Use: bool fact = is_factorial(void);
   This funnction returns true if a number
   is followed by factorial opertor. 
   Used as an indicator to call factorial function.
*/
bool is_factorial(){
    Token t = ts.get();
    if (t.kind == '!'){
        ts.putback(t);
        return true;
    }
    ts.putback(t);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for fully answering my questions! It all works fine now.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck on this and this idea never crossed me. I was almost there.